# How to set up angular 4 with webpack

Tags: angular

When i create angular-project(ng new projectname), it automatically build `inline.bundle.js`, `main.bundle.js`, `polyfills.bundle.js`, `styles.bundle.js`, `vender.bundle.js` in dist folder.
I can use the `dist/index.js` in backend.
So my question is "Ng4 build webpack automatically?"

Comment: Angular4 is just a framework. It has no idea about a building process, using webpack or anything else. Did you mean `angular-cii`? If so, please tag your question accordingly. Even in that case, `angular-cli` does not "build webpack", whatever that means, automatically or otherwise; it **uses** it.

Comment: I appreciate your reply @torazaburo, i've seen a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oZBuiqovOZ0, then what is that conception? And actually in dist folder, there are some packed files like above, and i can use those in my backend project like node.js

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you use angular-cli to create an angular 2 project, the project is automatically build with webpack.

Angular-cli changed from systemjs to webpack a while ago.

If you want to get the webpack configuration file you can use ng eject.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject

Edit based on comment:

There is no dependency on webpack in your angular project because angular/cli has a dependency on webpack and will install webpack for you. If you check your node_modules folder, you will see that webpack is there.

Answer (score -1):

from your project home directory, run the next command:

```
npm run build
```

this command will create a folder named `dist`.

in this folder you will find your files.
Edit the file `webpack.config.js` to change where the `webpack` places your files.